# Viewing of a list of images in Expandable List

Tags: android, multithreading, image, android-asynctask, expandablelistview

I have done a expandable list where child's (sub-items) are showing images from drawable folder or a text.

I want to do same thing with images from web. I have therefore also used the asynctask to avoid [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

This code is in my ExpandableListAdapter where i initialize the items and sub-items. Drawable and ImageView are globally defined so that all the functions can reach them without sending as parameters.

```
Drawable drawable;
ImageView imgView;


@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

String child = childList[groupPosition][childPosition];

    if(child.equalsIgnoreCase("none")){
        ImageView i = new ImageView(context);
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank_image_for_view_business);
        i.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        return i ;          
    }
      else if(child.startsWith("http")){
         imgView = new ImageView(context);
        new asyTask();
        return imgView;
    }else{
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        tv.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
        return tv;
    }
}

private Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String url){
      try{
          InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
          Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
          return d;
      }catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exc="+e);
          return null;
      }
}
```

And this is my asynchronous class:

```
private class asyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //show a progress bar
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);   
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        drawable  =  LoadImageFromWeb("http://www.ettinger.co.uk/var/ezflow_site/storage/images/collections/ettinger/ettinger-walkie-pen/lifestyle-navy-walkie-pen/navy-walkie-pen-gallery/wlkp_pens_navy-2/20569-2-eng-GB/wlkp_pens_navy-2.jpg"); 
        return 0;
    }
```

At the moment, in the expandable list i can only see images from drawable folder and textview's but there is no image from internet. What is the problem ?

Comment: do you have internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml? Also you should use a handler to set the drawable for the imageview.

Comment: yes i have internet permission. How can the handler help in this situation? can you give a example?

Comment: Since you're in a different thread than main thread you cannot set the drawable. just define a new handler attached to the UI thread or you can use runonmainthread. 
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //Your code to run in GUI thread here
        }
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it!

getChildView():

```
 ....    
 else if (child.startsWith("http")) {       
     Drawable image = ImageOperations(context,child,"image.jpg");
     ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
     imgView.setImageDrawable(image);
     imgView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
     return imgView;
     }....
```

This calls the following methods:

```
    private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

Thus, it is not necessary to create a other private class to show the images from internet in the  ExpandableListAdapter class. It works.